# Revert DB to old values in down method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

I need to create a rails migration which updates a db table entries.
On the up method is all good. I use first_or_initialize, assign_attributes then save!.
On the down method, i want to go back to the values which were initially saved. How can I go back to those values? Can I save those values in the up method and share them in down method?

thank you!

Comment: Did entirely depends on what your up method does. But in most cases, you cannot revert to the previous value unless you save the previous value in another column. Can you elaborate on how your up migration looks like?

Comment: This sounds like  a job that should be handled with database backup tools and not a migration.

Comment: you cannot go back to the initial values after updating entries through migration file. if you really want to do it then you can just create a backup of particular table or database (depending upon your requirement) so that you can read it while in down method. You can even use a logger to log attributes for tracing them back in worst case.